# Load properties files in session + Struts

Tags: java, properties, struts-1

Can we in Struts 1 load and set properties file in session, so that we need not to load the properties file in action at every request at the method level. Could anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Properties props = ...
// load your properties file

request.getSession().setAttribute("mypropertiesfile", props);
```

But it is not a good practice to use session to store such a things, why you don't simply use cache?

Comment: here is an example about how to use ehcache: http://ehcache.org/documentation/code-samples